# How to obtain a field value using reflection?

Tags: java

```
void showReflection() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    int i;
    for (Angajat a : angajati) {
        Class c = a.getClass();
        Field[] fd = c.getDeclaredFields();
        for (i = 0; i < fd.length; i++) {
            String name = fd[i].getName();
            Object o1 = fd[i].getType().newInstance();
            Object o = fd[i].get(o1);
            System.out.print(name + " " + o + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: I want to obtain the values of each field of my Angajat class using reflection

Comment: "and what happens instead? "

Comment: @Cristian, I suspect you want to find out the values of the fields on the objects in the `angajati` list?

Comment: Yes this is what I want, instead throws me an exception.But i discovered my mistake. Thanks

Comment: "instead throws me an exception" well Java have many exceptions and they are caused by different problems so you should consider [edit]ting your question to include more info about them (like stacktrace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is wrong:

```
Object o1 = fd[i].getType().newInstance();
Object o = fd[i].get(o1);
```

(because you end up looking at the fields of newly created objects.)

You probably want to do just

```
Object o = fd[i].get(a);
```

Comment: Consider adding `fd[i].setAccessible(true)` in case OP would want to read private fields.

Comment: Also it may be worth mentioning that since OP seems to know what enhanced-for-loop is (based on `for (Angajat a : angajati)` fragment) `Class c = a.getClass();
        Field[] fd = c.getDeclaredFields();
        for (i = 0; i < fd.length; i++) {` can be replaced with simple `for (Field f: a.getClass().getDeclaredFields())`

Comment: Feels kind of off topic for what's being asked. I like to keep my answers to the point.

Comment: OK, fair enough, but I will leave my comments just in case.